# How do i condense these set and where statements

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to update all values of 'did not see' in a single table to NULL.

I cannot figure out how to write one set statement

This is the code that I would like to write more elegantly

```
UPDATE  MovieSurvey
   SET field7 =NULL
   where field7 ='Did not see'
 
UPDATE  MovieSurvey 
   SET field8 =NULL 
   where field8 ='Did not see'
  
 UPDATE  MovieSurvey 
   SET field9 =NULL 
   where field9 ='Did not see'
   
UPDATE  MovieSurvey 
   SET field10 =NULL 
   where field10 ='Did not see'


UPDATE  MovieSurvey 
   SET field11 =NULL 
   where field11 ='Did not see'

UPDATE  MovieSurvey 
   SET field12 =NULL 
   where field12 ='Did not see'
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reference each column you want to update, but you *could* use a case expression in a single update.

```
update MovieSurvey set
 field7 = case when field7 = 'Did not see' then null else field7 end,
 field8 = case when field8 = 'Did not see' then null else field8 end,
 field9 = case when field9 = 'Did not see' then null else field9 end
... etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the function [`NULLIF()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#nullif) which will return either `NULL` if the column's value is `'Did not see'` or else the actual value of the column:

```
UPDATE MovieSurvey 
SET field7 = NULLIF(field7, 'Did not see'), 
    field8 = NULLIF(field8, 'Did not see'), 
    field9 = NULLIF(field9, 'Did not see'), 
    field10 = NULLIF(field10, 'Did not see'), 
    field11 = NULLIF(field11, 'Did not see'), 
    field12 = NULLIF(field12, 'Did not see')
WHERE 'Did not see' IN (field7, field8, field9, field10, field11, field12);
```